# QGIS 2.0.1 linking table issue, MSSQL 2008 database

Tags: qgis, attribute-joins, sql-server

I'm trying to link tables in QGIS 2.0.1 and MSSQL 2008 database.  I can link them but when I try to open the attribute table QGIS throws an error and shuts down creating a *.dmp file.  I saw that table joining when using databases that QGIS does not support MSSQL but the funny think is that QGIS 1.8 allows the join and attribute tables to work.  Anyone have any information regarding this?  I haven't been able to find anyone else having this problem online.

Comment: probably submit a ticket.  http://hub.qgis.org/projects/quantum-gis/issues

Comment: I can confirm a similar experience using QGIS 2.0.1 on Windows 7.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback - I will submit a ticket via the link above

Comment: I feel silly saying this, but for the above link, I can't find how to sign up so I can sign in so I can submit my issue (???)

Comment: Has there been any update to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

This similar issue https://hub.qgis.org/issues/9139 was fixed in 2.3 Master. It may have fixed your described problem too.